# How does Spring (Spring Boot) provide CSRF token to frontend?

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to add CSRF protection to a project which is based on Spring-Boot (particularly WebFlux).

What I have tried so far is below security configuration.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    http.
        ...
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(
            new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                    Arrays.asList(
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, FORM_LOGIN_URL),
                        ServerWebExchangeMatchers
                            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, PERMISSION_ENDPOINT)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .accessDeniedHandler(new CustomHttpStatusServerAccessDeniedHandler(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
        ...;

    return http.build();
}
```

But when I tried above configuration, I could not see anything related to a CSRF token being pushed from server to browser. Is it not by default being pushed to clients? If so what would be the cleaner way to provide CSRF token to client (browser)? In which spring document this is mentioned. (I followed this one -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html)

P.S. (hoping these following information are of any use for an answer)

- My login form is not being served by Spring Boot Webflux application. It is served by a angular application running on a different domain (different IP & Port). That is why I have a `FORM_LOGIN_URL` constant in above configuration, which is used as `.loginPage(FORM_LOGIN_URL)`. I have customized the `.authenticationSuccessHandler()` to redirect to `PERMISSION_ENDPOINT` which worked as intended up until.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is a bit poorly documented, but apparently the csrf-token wont be saved unless you subscribe to the result.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

   final CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository cookieServerCsrfTokenRepository = new CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository();
        cookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.setCookieHttpOnly(false);

    http.csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(cookieServerCsrfTokenRepository)
            .and()
            .cors()

             ...
}

// Add a tiny webfilter that just subscribes
@Bean
public WebFilter addCsrfToken() {
    return (exchange, next) -> exchange.<Mono<CsrfToken>>getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName())
                .doOnSuccess(token -> {}) // do nothing, just subscribe :/
                .then(next.filter(exchange));
}
```

the above solution works well if you are using functional endpoints. You can also use a `@ControllerAdvice` approach.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityControllerAdvice {@ModelAttribute Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Mono<CsrfToken> csrfToken = exchange.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        return csrfToken.doOnSuccess(token -> exchange.getAttributes()
                .put(CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.DEFAULT_CSRF_ATTR_NAME, token));
    }
}
```

There is an open bug report for this on github

[CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository does not add cookie](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5766)

Comment: thanks mate! This was a huge headache for me past days. Anyway let me ask you another question. How did you find this  open bug report on github? Is there a trick you use when stumble upon such a problem, glad if you share it ;) . Thanks again!

Comment: naah, its just google man.. i usually read the spring documentation very thoroughly, i look through the source code what stuff does, and then i google and read. The spring documentation is so so so interesting and good once you start understanding how things work together. I built a login system a while back and had the same problem as you and i googled for instance `CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository github` and that was the second hit.

Comment: :D well I'll keep what you mentioned in mind for the next time. Thanks again mate!